# Исчезают все данные с Лист

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc

Я делаю таблицу в которой есть кнопка EDIT, при нажатии ее, открывается страница с деталями водителя, можно изменить детали, после, когда нажимаю кнопку SAVE, у меня происходит это [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть контролер List, он создает таблицу, он работает, но когда вторично я хочу загрузить таблицу, то выдает ошибку, вот мой Controller

```
public class DriverTaxiController : Controller
{

  static  List<Drivers> Driver = new List<Drivers>();
    public static  int numLine = -1;

    // GET: DriverTaxi
    public ActionResult List()
    {

      //  if (Driver.Count == 0)
       // {
            Driver.Add(new Drivers() { Line = 1, NumberLicens = "123456", FirstName = "Evgeny", LastName = "Ryvkin", PhoneNumber = "0546819725", StartWork = "12/10/17", DateCheckEyes = "13/10/17"});
            Driver.Add(new Drivers() { Line = 2, NumberLicens = "123457", FirstName = "Moshe", LastName = "Kohen", PhoneNumber = "0546819725", StartWork = "12/10/17", DateCheckEyes = "13/10/17" });
            Driver.Add(new Drivers() { Line = 3, NumberLicens = "123458", FirstName = "Dana", LastName = "Multy", PhoneNumber = "0546819725", StartWork = "12/10/17", DateCheckEyes = "13/10/17" });
      //  }

        ViewBag.Drivers = Driver;
        return View();
    }


    public ActionResult MyAction(int  id=0)
    {


       // int numberLine = Convert.ToInt32(lineDriver);//convert string to int
       for(int i = 0; i < Driver.Count; i++)
        {

            if(Driver[i].Line == id)
            {
                ViewBag.nl = Driver[i].NumberLicens;
                ViewBag.fn = Driver[i].FirstName;
                ViewBag.ln = Driver[i].LastName;
                ViewBag.phone = Driver[i].PhoneNumber;
                ViewBag.start = Driver[i].StartWork;
                ViewBag.eye = Driver[i].DateCheckEyes;
                ViewBag.line = Driver[i].Line;

            }
        }

         numLine = id;

        return View();
    }//end class MyAction


  /*  public ActionResult MyAction()
    {

        return View();
    }*/
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update()
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            numLine--;
            Driver[numLine].NumberLicens = Request.Form["NumberLicens"];
            Driver[numLine].FirstName = Request.Form["FirstName"];
            Driver[numLine].LastName = Request.Form["LastName"];
            Driver[numLine].PhoneNumber = Request.Form["PhoneNumber"];
            Driver[numLine].StartWork = Request.Form["StartWork"];
            Driver[numLine].DateCheckEyes = Request.Form["DateCheckEyes"];

            return View("List2");
        }
        else
        {
            return View("MyAction");
        }

    }

    public ActionResult CreateForm()
    {


        return View();
    }
```

Это таблица

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Number Licens</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <th>Start Work</th>
            <th>Date Cheking the Eyes</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (Drivers p in ViewBag.Drivers)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@p.Line</td>
            <td>@p.NumberLicens</td>
            <td>@p.FirstName &nbsp; @p.LastName </td>
            <td>@p.PhoneNumber</td>
            <td>@p.StartWork</td>
            <td>@p.DateCheckEyes</td>



            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "MyAction", "DriverTaxi", new { id = p.Line }, null)
                 @*<input type="hidden" name="DriverName" value="hello" />
    <input type="submit" name="123" value="Edit" />
        *@
          </td>
                <td>addres</td>
                <td>email</td>
                <td><input id="Button2" type="submit" value="Delete" name="@p.NumberLicens" /></td>
            </tr>
```

Это Edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>MyAction</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "DriverTaxi"))
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.NumberLicens, new { @Value = @ViewBag.nl }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.NumberLicens)
        <br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.FirstName, new { @Value = @ViewBag.fn })
        <br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.LastName, new { @Value = @ViewBag.ln })
        <br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.PhoneNumber, new { @Value = @ViewBag.phone })
        <br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.StartWork, new { @Value = @ViewBag.start })
        <br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.DateCheckEyes, new { @Value = @ViewBag.eye })
        <br />

        @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Line)


        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
}
```

Спасибо заранее

Comment: в посте не заполняешь viewbag

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое!